# camel file moving to error directory on permission denied

Tags: apache-camel

I have a route which polls a directory and sends the files to multiple locations.

I have set the configuration to delete on success and move to error on failure.

Question:
I was testing by denying write permissions to the file on the source folder which is being polled. The file transfer failed and the file was moved to the error folder and deleted from source folder.
If the file did not have write permissions and IO exception with permission denied was thrown, how was Camel File component able to move the file to the error folder?

And to clarify, we are doing a simple file transfer, and don't need to process the file.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30531/mv-file-without-write-permission-to-the-source-file

Comment: you could catch and handle the exception and then write it to an error folder http://camel.apache.org/error-handling-in-camel.html
http://camel.apache.org/try-catch-finally.html
http://camel.apache.org/exception-clause.html

Comment: @pvpkiran so how come the file goes to .error when I have not set the delete option to false? It is by default false and moves the file to .camel folder on success. We did not want the headache of maintaining the processed files hence deleting. So if we don't need write permission on the file to process, camel should have moved to .camel folder when the file had read permission

Answer (score 0):

You wrote you got an `IOException` in your test, so obviously Camel had not enough permissions to process the file.

Regarding read permissions should be enough to read the file: I suspect that this is not enough because of file locking or a similar thing. You could give it a try to set `readLock=none`. Perhaps this removes the need for write permissions.

For the successful handling of the error: As the link of @pvpkiran says, Camel does not need permission on the file to move it, but on the directory. The file itself is not changed.

Comment: Thanks. I got why it moved on error. readLock=none is the default behavior. http://camel.apache.org/file2.html. Just curious why would camel need write permissions, to move it sucessfully, if delete=true is not set.